# Convert a matrix [121,131000] to an image builder c++

Tags: c++

I would like to find a function (like `imshow` in Python) in C++ builder Embarcadero, because I want to convert a matrix `[121,131000]` to image or to create a cartography for my matrix.

Comment: Did you look at [stb_image](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) for a simple way of saving in-memory buffers to image files?

Comment: Hi Botje, no i'm not. can we use stb image in Builder C++. I can convert a matrix [m,n] with m,n < 8000pixel, but for m or n > 8000 pixel, i can not convert it without suppression some pixel.

Comment: stb_image is a header-only library, so yes, you can use it.

Comment: Do you have an example using stb_image?

Comment: I found one here. https://github.com/nothings/stb